# How do you structure if statements with multiple values?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to assign a boolean a false value if the `int` value `day` is the 31st, and the `int` value `month` is any of the following, 4,6,9,11.
What I currently have is not working, how should it be structured?

```
if (day == 31 && month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
{
      validity = false;
}
```

Comment: Use parenthesis to structure your conditions properly. Operator precedence is the reason this doesn't work the way you want it to

Comment: The condition you currently have will be interpreted as `if ( (day == 31 && month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11) )`, seeing as `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) is some documentation about operator precendence to help you along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Granted, I could go on about operator precedence (which one goes first), but really, you should never have to worry about that because you should *always* be *very explicit* about how you want something to be evaluated. Use your parentheses to do so.

You can use newer features of C# to make it even more clear what you're doing:

```
if ((day is 31) && (month is 4 or 6 or 9 or 11))
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are valid, but here is my example if you want to shorten expression, what if you need to compare more month values, you can put all values in array and search if month value is contained in array.

```
if(day == 31 && new int[] { 4, 6, 9, 11 }.Contains(month))
{
}
```

Also you can create extension method name In and check if your month value is contained in array.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] array)
    {
        return array.Contains(value);
    }
}

if (day.In(31) && month.In(4, 6, 9, 11))
{
}
```

But as I said this depends on you, use what is more readable to you or someone else who look at your code :)